# Cmd Line read terminal color

Tags: bash, terminal, colors

What I want is a from the prompt command line that will tell me what the screen background color is.
If it's black, then I will make the foreground (in .bashrc) an appropriate color and if white background then I can make the foreground a different color.

I want a single .bashrc script that I can use in different places and the script "handles" the foreground text color based on the background default screen color for that given Linux VM.  (I have hundreds of different Linux VMs and I build and tear down VMS almost daily.)

This way I could have if term_background is black then foreground text is yellow.....

Thanks in advance for your help.....

Prof Scott

I have different lines in my .bashrc to manage this, but it requires intervention to switch....

Comment: The shell has some color control via escape sequences, but colors are typically settings of the terminal emulator. https://unix.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit for this question.

Comment: Whare are you setting the background color?

Comment: Would this help ?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172548/how-to-determine-the-current-color-of-the-console-output